# Letting PHP errors make their way

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm developing a very simple but (hopefully) solid framework that just fits my needs. No more things then the really needed one.
I know that someone of you might find me the last "re inventor of the wheel", but I believe in this project and I think that other framework are complex for no reason some times; and we all know that bugs and errors grow exponentially as the framework complexity.

I came to the problem of handling errors: PHP errors, framework errors (PHP errors group) etc.
There are a lot of ways to do that but I usually prefer the simple one.

Should I manage all the PHP errors that can occur during the initialization of the framework with Exceptions or `set_error_handler()` or should I build a simple error handler that show (if we are in developer mode) or log (if we are not in developer mode) the errors?

For example:

```
include('file.php'); // required files for the application
```

should I check for it and return "nice looking" error messages such as "The framework cannot run because a file is missing". Or should I let PHP error trigger its own error?
How would you manage this type or errors?

Comment: I would say that "bugs and errors" mainly come from reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Remember, you're using PHP, so you can make a nicely formatted HTML+CSS error log  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you are just mixing the matters.

There are actually two persons you have to notify

1. A programmer
2. A user.

Understanding that, you will see that there is no problem what to choose: both.

For the programmer, the default PHP handler is enough. Driven with `display_errors` and `log_errors` settings PHP will do exactly what you want: `show (if we are in developer mode) or log (if we are not in developer mode) the errors`.

For the user (and a search engine) a "nice looking" 503 error page is obligatory. 
Of course, without whatever details like "file is missing". Just an apology page.

The only question is how to trigger that. 
A good reason to make use of a custom error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Leaking php errors can be quite dangerous security-wise, because it can reveal the innards of your application and server. It is generally good practice to switch [`display_errors Off`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) for production and use a custom error handler instead. For development, it does not really matter.

I will cite the php doc on `display_errors`:

> This is a feature to support your development and should never be used on production systems (e.g. systems connected to the internet).